# How to create a process that cannot be killed?

Tags: java, windows, process

I am running my java application. It shows up in the process tab of the task manager. I dont want users to kill that process?

And if possible i dont want my process to be in the process list also.

My application is a LAN administrator. I need to log client machines. If its possible for the user to kill my process there is no use in creating such an application.

Comment: Except from it being in java, sounds like malware to me.

Comment: is this windows-xp specific ?

Comment: "And if possible i dont want my process to be in the process list also." Normal program will not need it.

Comment: "I dont want users to kill that process?" are you asking us what you want :-|

Comment: do you perhaps also want your process to be undetectable by antivirus software?

Comment: My application is a LAN administrator. I need to log client machines. If its possible for the user to kill my process there is no use in creating such an application.

Comment: Most users won't even know that it exists; let alone have any reason to kill it.

Comment: @phoenix24 no..its noy windows -xp specific

Comment: LAN administrator? XD that sounds a lot like the good old BackOrifice :-p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the user will use the virtual machine to run your program, he can always kill the JVM :)

Comment: What if i use some java launcher. Can he even then kill my process.

Comment: Yes, this is completely independent from the programming language in use. Just don't even try (there are ways --> root kits) but it is a bad way for so many reasons

Answer (score 17):

IMO, creating process that cannot be killed is negating the user's right to control his / her machine.  I cannot think of any moral justification for doing this ... whether or not it is technically possible, and whether or not you may have some "business" reason for doing it.

Comment: +1 Whereas administrators (e.g., in shops with locked-down workstations) have a perfectly valid reason for preventing users from killing any processes *at all*; that's a totally different use case.

Answer (score 7):

A process owned by the current user can always be killed.

Edit: unless the process is system-related (which should then be run as a different user, like in Linux), there is an ideological concept in which the user should always have the right to know what's going on and be able to  take control over the user's running processes (after all, it *is* her user account).